# What does a while statement that only sets 2 pointers equal, do?

Tags: c, pointers, while-loop

we are currently learning how Pointers work in C.
I have this very short code of a copymethod of Strings in C, that was given to us from a tutor. I tried to explain its function in my own words but I am unsure if I have understood it correctly and would appreciate if somebody could correct my mistakes and answer my questions about it.

```
void copy ( char ∗ source , char ∗ dest) {
    while (∗dest++ = ∗source++);
}
```

> "Copy is a function with 2 Paramaters source and dest, which are both pointers of type `char`. The function calls a `while` statement which sets the dereferenced `dest`, incremented by `1 * sizeof(char)`, equal to the dereferenced and incremented (by `1*sizeof(char)`) `source`."

What exactly does the `while` statement do? From my understanding `*dest` means that I am getting the `char` which `dest` points to, is that correct? But why would a `while` statement only set 2 pointers equal to each other, I don't really get it.

I appreciate any help, thank you!

Comment: it doesn't "only set 2 pointers";  it also increments them (the pointers; not the values being set).

Comment: "*dest means that I am getting the char which dest **points to**". The assignment is about what the pointers _point to_ as you said yourself.

Comment: The expression `∗dest++ = ∗source++` not only copies (and *then* increments the pointers) but also has a value. That value will be `0` (false) when the string terminator is copied, but non-zero (true) when a character is copied. It is equivalent to `while ((*dest++ = *source++) != '\0') {}`

Comment: @Mat So i am setting whatever dest is pointing equal to what ever source is pointing, but I increment them before that, right?

Comment: @WeatherVane ah thank you I didn't know that!

Comment: No, `dest++` is **post**-increment. `++dest` is **pre**-increment.

Comment: This is not a safe way to copy strings, there should be a parameter for the length of the source string. This assumes that there is going to be a '\0' at the end or the source string, but if there isn't one you would overstep the dest string's size.

Answer (score 2):

This is the terse way to write an implementation of `strcpy`.

It is equivalent to the longer, but easier to follow

```
while (*dest = *source) {
    dest++;
    source++;
}
```

`*dest = *source` copies one `char` from the source to the destination. The result is zero if a zero byte was copied, at which time the loop ends.

Adding the increment to the condition is possible because the pointer dereferenced is the pointer value *before* the increment.

Comment: maybe even more detailed: `while (*src != 0) { *dest = *src; dest++; src++; } *dest = 0;` ... BTW you're using `source` and `src` in your snippet.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to start evaluating the expressions from the inner to the outer side.  An important thing is to take into consideration that the body of the loop is empty (the `;` at the right parenthesis indicates that the loop is executing the null statement --do nothing--, so everything must happen in the test expression).

The expression in the `while` test is not a test for equity, but an assignment.  The equals operator is written doubling the `=`, as in `==`, while `=` is used to assign the value of the right subexpression to the variable on the left side.

The variable on the left side is `*dest++`.  A bit complicated expression that includes a dereference operator `*` and an autoincrement operator `++`.  The `++` takes higher preference, so it is acted first:  the pointer is incremented, and the value returned by this subexpression is the value of the pointer **before** it was incremented.  This means that the value of the pointer being used is the one it had before the expression `dest++` was evaluated, and the `*` operator states the `char` variable pointed to by `dest`.  So the place where the value will be stored in the assignment is the value pointed to by `dest`, and the pointer will be incremented before the end of the whole expression ends --but after the value is used--.  The right side of the assignment show what is going to be assigned.  As the expression is the same, I will pass quickly over it.  The value assigned is the one pointed to by the `source` variable.  It is incremented once the value is taken, and the value stored in the place of `dest` is filled with the character of the variable pointed by `src`.  After that, both pointers are incremented, so the next time the test expression is evaluated, the characters involved will be the next source assigned to the next destination character.  So, in this point, when the loop will be finished?  Well, the value of an assignment expression is precisely the value assigned to the destination target, so in this case is the character copied from source to destination.  And the test will fail, when the character copied happens to be zero (or false in C terms).  As you see, there's nothing left to be put in the body of the loop.

This sample is famous for being an example of how cryptic C can get to.  It appears in the two editions of "The C programming language" of Kernighan & Ritchie, the inventors of the language, and is accompanied by a comment that says something more or less like this:  This is a bit obscure but every programmer that is proud of being proficient at C coding must be capable of interpreting this with a bit of care.  (indeed the loop variables in the source are one letter `s` and `d`, i think)